# Use ".then" from JqueryAJAX to "normal" function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

The situation looks as follows:

```js
$("#someThing").datepicker({
  //someOptions,
  onSelect: function() {
    /*Does some async stuff*/
    AJAXCALL();
    /*execute AFTER ajaxcall has finished*/
    foo();
  }
})


function AJAXCALL() {
  $.post('someUrl.php', {
    //nothing to transmit
  }, someFunction(data))
}
```

The thing is,  leads into a cascade of functions which process the DataFromTheDatabase.
The code inside this cascade is either synchronous, or there are async/await sections inside which synchronize the code properly.

Ultimately, both the initial `AJAXCALL()` and the successive functions MUST have finished before `foo()` is executed.

Would it be sufficient to do the following:

```js
$("#someThing").datepicker({
  //someOptions,
  onSelect: function() {
    AJAXCALL().then(() => {
      foo()
    })
  }
})


function AJAXCALL() {
  return $.post('someUrl.php', {
    //nothing to transmit
  }).then((data) => someFunction(data))
}
```

Comment: The code snippet tool as a build in tidy functionality, please make use of it to bring the code into a form that is easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current version of jQuery is  already sufficient to write it like you did in second example:

```js
$("#someThing").datepicker({
  //someOptions,
  onSelect: function() {
    AJAXCALL().then(() => {
      foo()
    })
  }
})


function AJAXCALL() {
  return $.post('someUrl.php', {
    //nothing to transmit
  }).then((data) => someFunction(data))
}
```

So `someFunction` will be called before `foo` is called.

And you don't need to write `.then((data) => someFunction(data))` instead you could just write `.then(someFunction)`. Same is with `foo`:

```js
$("#someThing").datepicker({
  //someOptions,
  onSelect: function() {
    AJAXCALL().then(foo)
  }
})


function AJAXCALL() {
  return $.post('someUrl.php', {
    //nothing to transmit
  }).then(someFunction)
}
```

Comment: Okay, so if I write ".then(someFunction)", the result from the AJAX Call is still inserted into the parameter of "someFunction()"? Would writing ".then(someFunction(data))" or  ".then(someFunction())" have the same result? I've never written out a function call without the "()". The IDE (currently ATOM) doesn't even recognize it as a function (highlighting).^^

Comment: @ForeFather321 if you write `.then(someFunction(data))` or `.then(someFunction())` then the `someFunction` is called an the result of that function is passed to `.then`. I would be as if you write `var res = someFunction(data); $.post( ... ).then(res)`, so not that won't work.

Comment: @ForeFather321 your `.then((data) => someFunction(data))`, is as if you would write: `var callback =  (data) => someFunction(data);  $.post( ... ).then(callback)`. So for both `.then(someFunction)` and `.then((data) => someFunction(data))` you pass a function to `then` that is later called using data as first param. Using the arrow function would only be required, if you `someFunction` takes more then one argument, and/or `data` should not be the first  argument. e.g. `.then((data) => someFunction(data, {foo:'bar'}))` or `.then((data) => someFunction({foo:'bar'}, data))`

Comment: Wow, thanks for your comprehensive explanation, this helped a lot with understanding! :))

Answer (score 1):

Use when then https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

```
$("#someThing").datepicker({
  //someOptions,
  onSelect: function() {
    $.when( AJAXCALL() ).then(() => {
      foo()
    })
  }
})


function AJAXCALL() {
  return $.post('someUrl.php', {
    //nothing to transmit
  }).then((data) => someFunction(data));
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that `$.when` is required here? Under which circumstances would it not work correctly if only `AJAXCALL().then(() => {` this is used?

Comment: Why did you remove `.then((data) => someFunction(data))` now `someFunction` is never called?

Comment: because this foo() will be called after ajax call completes. so we already have then in $.when( AJAXCALL() ).then(()

Comment: The question of the OP is `Ultimately, both the initial AJAXCALL() and the successive functions [someFunction] MUST have finished before foo() is executed.` But in your current solution `someFunction` is not called at all.

Comment: But the original question in my first comment still remains: Why do you think that `$.when` is required here?